# How do I specify criteria for excluding documents from a query?

Tags: mongodb

This seems like a simple enough question but I haven't found an answer:
I'm using MongoDB and I want to perform a query in which I provide search criteria, but I also want to carve out an exception where certain documents are excluded based on criteria.  For example, imagine a collection with the fields `name`, `age` and `gender`.

Retrieving everyone below a certain age?  Easy: `<collection>.find({'age':{'$lt':<maxAge>}})`
Retrieving all females below a certain age?  Piece of cake: `<collection>.find({'gender':female, 'age':{'$lt':<maxAge>}})`

But what about retrieving everyone, except if they are [female and below a certain age?].  You can easily negate a specific field with the '$ne' operator, but how do I negate everyone who matches a set of criteria?

Comment: Methinks there is a no way to negate all criterias.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to apply boolean logic to invert the AND into an OR of the negation of each term individually:

```js
collection.find({$or: [{age: {$gte: maxAge}}, {gender: {$ne: 'female'}}]})
```

or

```js
collection.find({$or: [{age: {$not: {$lt: maxAge}}}, {gender: {$ne: 'female'}}]})
```