# Check if particular field exists in mongoDb Collection,excluding one record

Tags: mongodb, database

I have collection, as shown below

```
  { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("58fe3768f997ca09d551c34e"), 
        "firstName" : "arbar", 
        "lastName" : "ame", 
        "email" : "test41@gmail.com", 
        "phone" : "9966589965", 
        "password" : "$2a$10$pgRWb8Db385A5BbicEDJ2erHuUQsAIVmjqVuccXj7x.1iptdY/z7a", 
        "team_id" : ObjectId("58ef6d0a11c37915acaf7c9b"), 
        "activated" : false, 
        "accessLevel" : NumberInt(6)
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("58fe37c2f997ca09d551c350"), 
        "firstName" : "Abrar Ahmed", 
        "lastName" : "asdf", 
        "email" : "test42@gmail.com", 
        "phone" : "9966158845", 
        "password" : "$2a$10$y3hPjuHeq0HVyukTnGCRT.k5xfSUH0z/mdGR8n7Gu09f7A7Z20bV6", 
        "team_id" : ObjectId("58ef6d0a11c37915acaf7c9b"), 
        "activated" : false, 
        "accessLevel" : NumberInt(6)
}
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

I am trying to check if email `test41@gmail.com` exists in this collection, if I use `this.collection.findOne({ email: 'test41@gmail.com' });` will look for all the records in a collection but how would I exclude one record in a collection by using _id field as reference to exclude.

Here the email is exists in one record of the collection with 
`"_id" : ObjectId("58fe3768f997ca09d551c34e"),` , but I want to exclude this record and search in rest of the records in a Collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I specify criteria for excluding documents from a query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512634/how-do-i-specify-criteria-for-excluding-documents-from-a-query)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `findOne`, use `find` to find all occurrences. Now if you want to exclude some document you can do by following

```
db.collection.find({$and: [{"email": "test41@gmail.com"}}, {"_id": {$ne: ObjectId("58fe3768f997ca09d551c34e")}}]})
```